# Flink: How to pass a dynamic path while writing to files using writeFileAsText(path)?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say I have a Stream with elements of type `String`. I want to write each element in the stream to a separate file in some folder. I'm using the following set up.

```
stream.writeAsText(path).setParallelism(1);
```

How do I make this path dynamic? I even tried adding `System.nanotime()` to the path to make it dynamic. But it still doesn't seem to work, everything gets written to a single file.

Comment: Please mention in question, How you tried

Comment: @Tarun What more information do you want? It's all in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that DataStream.writeAsText() writes the entire content of the stream to the file at once, so you will only ever get a single file.

It looks like this will return a collection that you can use to output your strings as different files.

```
dataStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
@Override
public void flatMap(String value, Collector<String> out)
    throws Exception {
    for(String word: value.split(" ")){
        out.collect(word);
    }
}
});
```

Taken straight from the documentation here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/datastream_api.html

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: To your edit. The flat map operator still returns a DataStream, so I don't see how this is any different. Or did you mean writing to separate files within the flatMap() method?

Comment: I did mean writing them within the method, I can't find any actual method to iterate over DataStream objects within the documentation so I figured that was the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of use case is explicitly supported in Flink by the [Rolling File Sink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html) with a custom bucketer, or the newer and prefered [Streaming File Sink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html) with a custom BucketAssigner and RollingPolicy.